# How to stop the turtles for some time and kill both turtles if it is in some radius in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

How to stop / kill two turtles if they come in some radius? Rest of the turtles should not stop moving.

Comment: You will need to give us some more information about those turtles.

Comment: In a traffic 2 vehicles are moving in the same direction one after the other and if they touch each other it should stop and both have to disappear.

Comment: this is nowhere near enough information for anyone to help you unfortunately. what code do you already have? Ideally, you would show the code you have written that attempts to do this and to explain what's not working with it. Even if you have no idea how to approach the problem and therefore don't have starting code, you must have some code that moves the vehicles and that probably looks ahead at the vehicle in front, so may give a starting point.

Comment: ask turtles-here in-radius 1  [
           ask turtles  to stay for some time
       die  (both turtles)    ----------- something like this.

Answer (score 1):

## Asking all turtles to check their environment

Here's an example that might be helpful as a first attempt. Since the aim is to signal to a large set of turtles when to continue walking and die, you will need to create a procedure that asks all turtles to check their environment.

Naive Implementation:

```
to global-step
   ask turtles [ ifelse any? other turtles in-radius 3 [ die ] [ fd 1 ] ]
end
```

The naive implementation works well to remove turtles, but not all turtles are removed, since turtles would disappear with each turtle's check.

## Improvements with multiple agents

One way to improve this is through adding a turtles-own'd variable for marking the turtles as within a certain radius of a turtle.

Improved Version:

```
to global-step
   ask turtles [ 
      ifelse any? other turtles in-radius 3 
         [ set turtle-variable true ] 
         [ set turtle-variable false ] ]
   ask turtles [ ifelse turtle-variable [ die ] [ fd 1 ] ]
end
```